# Как подогнать html и css под разные устройства

Tags: html, css, django

Понимаю, что вопрос тупой, но мне хочется получить однозначный ответ. Как сайт должен определять, на каком устройстве он работает ? А то на мобильных устройствах всё плывёт:<
p.s На всякий случай, если это вдруг как-то связанно, то я работаю в Django

Comment: Устройства (как правило) не при чём - сайт должен адаптироваться под разные размеры экрана. А размеры экрана Вы можете изменять в отладчике браузера и таким образом тестировать поведение вёрстки.

Comment: `однозначный ответ`: **учитесь верстать**.

Comment: django тут каким боком?)

Comment: смотрите медиа запросы в css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сайт должен определять, на каком устройстве он работает ?

Вариант javascript, определяет устройство:

```js
const devices = new RegExp('Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini', "i");
if (devices.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  alert("Вы используете мобильное устройство")
} else {
  alert("Вы используете ПК")
}
```

> А то на мобильных устройствах всё плывёт

Например, чтобы определить устройство и задать нужный нам стиль для определенного элемента на сайте, используем вариант с выше приведенным кодом javascript:

```js
const block = document.getElementById('block');
const devices = new RegExp('Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini', "i");
if (devices.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  block.classList.add("mobil");
} else {
  block.classList.add("pk");
}
```

```css
.mobil::before {
  content: "Вы используете мобильное устройство";
  background: red;
}

.pk::before {
  content: "Вы используете ПК";
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Или воспользуемся простым медиа-запросом:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #block::before {
    content: "Вы используете мобильное устройство";
    background: red;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  #block::before {
    content: "Вы используете ПК";
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Или так:

```css
@media handheld {
  #block::before {
    content: "Вы используете мобильное устройство";
    background: red;
  }
}

@media screen {
  #block::before {
    content: "Вы используете ПК";
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Подробнее о медиа-запросах можно почитать, например, здесь: [Медиа-запросы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)

Дополнительно будет полезно почитать о том, что такое [адаптивный веб-дизайн](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&lr=959).

Желаю успехов в обучении!

---

upd по комментарию:

> А есть возможность в зависимости от определившегося устройства
> присоединять разные css файлы ?

Пример подключения внешнего css-файла через javascript:

```
const linkCSS = document.createElement("link");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(linkCSS);
linkCSS.rel = "stylesheet";
linkCSS.type = "text/css";
linkCSS.href = "ваш_файл.css";
```

Но лучше этого не делать.

Comment: это никак не поможет автору решить проблему с плывущей вёрсткой )) дело ведь не в устройстве, а в вёрстке

Comment: А есть возможность в зависимости от определившегося устройства присоединять разные css файлы ?